# How create procedure to update everyday

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-merge

I need to change this script so that it updates data every day, because insert new data every day

```sql
MERGE INTO t_customer_statistics tcs
USING (
  SELECT rowid rid,
         LEAD(TRX_DATE, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY cuid ORDER BY TRX_DATE DESC) AS prev_dt,
         LAG(TRX_DATE, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY cuid ORDER BY TRX_DATE DESC) AS next_dt
  FROM t_customer_statistics
) src
ON ( tcs.ROWID = src.rid )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET LIFECYCLE_STATUS = CASE
               WHEN prev_dt IS NULL
               THEN 'acquired'
               WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(tcs.TRX_DATE, 'MM'), TRUNC(src.prev_dt)) <= 1
               THEN 'existing'
               ELSE 'reactivated'
               END
               ||
               CASE
               WHEN COALESCE(src.next_dt, SYSDATE) >= tcs.TRX_DATE + INTERVAL '90' DAY
               THEN ', sleeping'
               END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't it update data every day?

There's no `WHERE` clause (which would restrict rows to be updated) and the only join condition is `ON ( tcs.ROWID = src.rid )` which is always true as you're basically updating the same table, based on data in that very table.

So, if your question is actually "how to run this `MERGE` automatically every day", then put it into a stored procedure which will be scheduled (by `DBMS_SCHEDULER` or older (but simpler) `DBMS_JOB`) to run every day.